# How to implement where criteria with Neo4jClient F#?

Tags: json, neo4j, f#, json.net, neo4jclient

I try to query count related nodes of a specific one with Neo4jClient in F#. But keep receiving the following error:

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type Newtonsoft.Json.JsonContainerAttribute.get_NamingStrategyType()'.

I just cannot find the answer in documentation of the packages. Filtering with the lambda function works in the "select" stage but not in "where".

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type User = { id : int; followers : int }

let tweetsCounted = 
  client.Cypher
    .Match("(u:User)-[:POSTED]->(t:Tweet)")
    .Where(fun u -> u.followers = 1000)
    .Return(fun (u : Cypher.ICypherResultItem) (t : Cypher.ICypherResultItem) -> u.As<User>(), t.Count())
    .Results
    .Select(fun (x, y) -> x.id, y)
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem lies - are you saying that the code above errors? If so - what makes it not error? By the `where` stage - do you mean the `.Where` on the client or another way?

Comment: I've just added some F# tests to the client (https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/pull/270) the `.Where` is working as expected, as is the `.Return` - maybe you could give me a failing test so I can look into more?

Comment: Thank you, first passing a parameter like solved the issue while lambda function way produced the mentioned error.
``
        .Where("u.followers = {followers}")
        .WithParams( {followers = filterUser.followers} )
``
I reset my connection, restarted FSI and cannot reproduce the issue. I can confirm that the script above runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just so this question has an answer.

I've added unit tests to test the functionality of F# with respect to `WHERE` and `RETURN` clauses, and they pass as expected (see http://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/pull/270).

The error as mentioned by @AnotherNewbie is not reproducible in their environment anymore either.